# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType not found

Tags: java, json, ant, jackson

I am using jackson libs in my application and when I build the code (using ant), the build is successful. And I have tried mock testing by using those methods in unit testing and its working fine. But when starting karaf, it gives me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType not found by com.project.test.application [224]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

And these are the jars I am downloading in my ivy.xml:

```
<dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-core" rev="2.4.4" transitive="false" />
<dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-annotations" rev="2.4.4" transitive="false" />
<dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-databind" rev="2.4.4" transitive="false" />
```

I have tried changing the versions, but still the same error. Do I have to load these jars after downloading? I have kept the default place as ivy-lib and that process is working for all the other jars I am downloading.
What is going wrong? Does this require a specific version or any other dependency? Or is there other way to load these jar files?

My classpath in build.xml

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${ivy.lib}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: where is your code for com.test.application class ?

Comment: When running your test how are you specifying the classpath? You need to include more detail from your build.xml file. The class exists in the jackson-databind dependency: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType%22%20AND%20g%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.core%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.4.4%22

Comment: My classpath in build.xml is the ivy-lib folder. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was getting this error because someone else in some other class was using `org.codehaus.jackson` package and I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson` package. And because of this conflict of jars, it was throwing this `ClassNotFoundException`. Once I removed and replaced those fasterxml jars with codehaus jars, it started working fine.

Answer (score 4):

We can add below dependencies in our pom.xml and all type of jackson error will be resolved

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't understand- why are you explicitly excluding core and annotations and adding them later?

Answer (score 0):

As for me, version 2.8.6 didn't work with Spring MVC context (w/o Boot) while 2.9.4
works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens with a library method throwing this error - check the dependency on the library and update your project libraries to match the same.
My project had jackson 2.10. Library had 2.15.
2.15 had a class that 2.10 did not (same class, but were named differently), causing this issue.
Solution was to upgrade the jackson version in my project.